# Using boto to invoke lambda functions how do I do so asynchronously?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-lambda

SO I'm using boto to invoke my lambda functions and test my backend. I want to invoke them asynchronously. I have noted that "invoke_async" is deprecated  and should not be used. Instead you should use "invoke" with an InvocationType of "Event" to do the function asynchronously.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the responses from the functions when they return though. I have tried the following:

```
payload3=b"""{
"latitude": 39.5732160891,
"longitude": -119.672918997,
"radius": 100
}"""

client = boto3.client('lambda')
for x in range (0, 5):
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName="loadSpotsAroundPoint",
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=payload3
    )
    time.sleep(15)
    print(json.loads(response['Payload'].read()))
    print("\n")
```

Even though I tell the code to sleep for 15 seconds, the response variable is still empty when I try and print it. If I change the invokation InvokationType to "RequestResponse" it all works fine and response variable prints, but this is synchronous. Am I missing something easy? How do i execute some code, for example print out the result, when the async invokation returns??

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An asynchronously executed AWS Lambda function doesn't return the result of execution. If an asynchronous invocation request is successful (i.e. there were no errors due to permissions, etc), AWS Lambda immediately returns the HTTP status code [202 ACCEPTED](https://httpstatuses.com/202) and bears no further responsibility for communicating any information about the outcome of this asynchronous invocation.

From the documentation of [AWS Lambda Invoke action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_ResponseSyntax):

> ## Response Syntax
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 StatusCode
> X-Amz-Function-Error: FunctionError
> X-Amz-Log-Result: LogResult
>
> Payload
> ```
>
> ### Response Elements
>
> If the action is successful, the service sends back the following HTTP
>   response.
>
> #### StatusCode
>
> The HTTP status code will be in the 200 range for successful request.
>   For the `RequestResponse` invocation type this status code will be 200.
>   **For the `Event` invocation type this status code will be 202**. For the `DryRun` invocation type the status code will be 204.
>
> [...]
>
> The response returns the following as the HTTP body.
>
> #### Payload
>
> It is the JSON representation of the object returned by the Lambda
>   function. **This is present only if the invocation type is
>   `RequestResponse`.**

Answer (score 56):

There is a difference between an *'async AWS lambda invocation'* and *'async python code'*. When you set the `InvocationType` to `'Event'`, [by definition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax), it does not ever send back a response.

In your example, `invoke()` immediately returns `None`, and does not implicitly start up anything in the background to change that value at a later time (thank goodness!). So, when you look at the value of `response` 15 seconds later, it's still `None`.

It seems what you really want is the `RequestResponse` invocation type, with asynchronous Python code. You have a bunch of options to choose from, but my favorite is [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). Another is [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Here's an example using `concurrent.futures`:

(If you're using Python2 you'll need to `pip install futures`)

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import json

payload = {...}

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    futs = []
    for x in xrange(0, 5):
        futs.append(
            executor.submit(client.invoke,
                FunctionName   = "loadSpotsAroundPoint",
                InvocationType = "RequestResponse",
                Payload        = bytes(json.dumps(payload))
            )
        )
    results = [ fut.result() for fut in futs ]

print results
```

Another pattern you might want to look into is to use the `Event` invocation type, and have your Lambda function push messages to SNS, which are then consumed by another Lambda function. You can check out a tutorial for SNS-triggered lambda functions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html).

Comment: as a followup note, i had to use `bytes(json.dumps(payload), "utf-8")` or it would throw an error

Comment: and I had to use `Payload = json.dumps(payload)`

Comment: @MohammadSadoughi The `ThreadPoolExecutor` above does this on multiple threads of a single processor. You might be thinking of `ProcessPoolExecutor`, which starts multiple processes (and thus can utilize multiple processors).

Comment: InvocationType = 'Event' returns immediately
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke

Answer (score 21):

The following are a python function that accepts lambda-function-Name to invoke and payload to send to that function.

It invokes the lambda function by boto3 client.

```
import boto3, json, typing

def invokeLambdaFunction(*, functionName:str=None, payload:typing.Mapping[str, str]=None):
    if functionName == None:
        raise Exception('ERROR: functionName parameter cannot be NULL')
    payloadStr = json.dumps(payload)
    payloadBytesArr = bytes(payloadStr, encoding='utf8')
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    return client.invoke(
        FunctionName=functionName,
        InvocationType="RequestResponse",
        Payload=payloadBytesArr
    )
```

And usage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    payloadObj = {"something" : "1111111-222222-333333-bba8-1111111"}
    response = invokeLambdaFunction(functionName='myLambdaFuncName',  payload=payloadObj)
    print(f'response:{response}')
```

Comment: to get output: `response["Payload"].read()`